# How to create dynamic text boxes with numeration using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How I can create dynamic text boxes with numeration using jQuery?

This is my code now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        counter = 1;
    }).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        counter = counter + 1;

        var controlForm = $('.controls'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:last'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:first) .btn-add')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-danger')
            .html('-');
        currentEntry.find('.input-box')
            .attr('name', 'subject')
            .attr('placeholder', 'Materia ' + String(counter));
    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
        $(this).parents('.entry:last').remove();
        counter = counter - 1
        $(this).parents('.entry').each(function() {
            $(this).parents('.entry:last').attr('placeholder', 'Materia ' + String(counter));
        })

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="type-elements" class="controls">
    <div class="form-row entry">
        <div class="form-inline mb-3">
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-link text-success btn-add mr-1" href="">+</a>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-1 input-box" placeholder="Materia 1" required name="subject">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <select class="custom-select mb-3" required multiple size="3" name="classes">
                <option disabled>Seleziona una o più classi</option>
                <option>2DM</option>
                <option>2AM</option>
                <option>2DM</option>
                <option>2AM</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to re-order numbers when a textbox is removed, so I will always have:

.+ Textbox 1

.- Textbox 2

.- Textbox 3

ecc.

(the dot is only to avoid the auto-unordered list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function to control at every click how many `.input-box` there are in the page to change its placeholder with a progressive number.

```
function controllo() {
    var counter = 1;
    $(".input-box").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Materia ' + counter);
        counter++;
    })
}
```

I also commented some lines of code. That's it.

The result:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //counter = 1;
}).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //counter = counter + 1;

    var controlForm = $('.controls'),
        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:last'),
        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:first) .btn-add')
        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
        .removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-danger')
        .html('-');
    currentEntry.find('.input-box')
        .attr('name', 'subject')
        //.attr('placeholder', 'Materia ' + String(counter));
    controllo();
}).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.entry:last').remove();
    /*counter = counter - 1
    $(this).parents('.entry').each(function() {
        $(this).parents('.entry:last').attr('placeholder', 'Materia ' + String(counter));
    })*/

    e.preventDefault();
    controllo();
    return false;
});

function controllo() {
    var counter = 1;
    $(".input-box").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Materia ' + counter);
        counter++;
    })
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="type-elements" class="controls">
    <div class="form-row entry">
        <div class="form-inline mb-3">
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-link text-success btn-add mr-1" href="">+</a>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-1 input-box" placeholder="Materia 1" required name="subject">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <select class="custom-select mb-3" required multiple size="3" name="classes">
                <option disabled>Seleziona una o più classi</option>
                <option>2DM</option>
                <option>2AM</option>
                <option>2DM</option>
                <option>2AM</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahahahah... not too far, my friend. You're welcome! Mandi mandi ;-)